# set focus on first textbox of listview in insert mode using ajax

Tags: asp.net, listview, webforms, updatepanel

Here's a nice one:

Page using an UpdatePanel. Inside is a ListView. It has 1 TextBox. When the user clicks a button i set the ListView's InsertItemPosition to top.

Q: How do i set focus on the TextBox?

Comment: Might be worth posting your Markup for the ListView and the code for your Button Click event so that other users can help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `ScriptManager` control on the page you could use it to `SetFocus` to the `TextBox` control.  You would need to do this in the code behind within your button click event.

**EDIT:**  This should allow you to get to the TextBox control in the InsertItemTemplate.  **NOTE:** You will need to change the control name in the `FindControl` method to the name of the `TextBox` in your `InsertItemTemplate`.

**Example:**

```
TextBox tb = ListView1.InsertItem.FindControl("tbName") as TextBox;

if (tb != null)
{
   ScriptManager1.SetFocus(tb);
}
```

Comment: where does TextBox1 come from? At what point can i pull it out of the control collection after i set the ListView to insert mode? (i suppose that's what i need to do to get to it).

Comment: TextBox1 would be the TextBox control itself, but I think I misunderstood the question.  You mean the TextBox control itself is within the ListView Control and not directly on the page?

Comment: The TextBox is inside the InsertItemTemplate of the ListView.

Comment: @Jeroen I've updated the answer to reflect getting the TextBox from within the InsertItemTemplate.

Comment: It's the first thing i have already tried but i can't get the TextBox. FindControl keeps returning null. In which Page Event do you imagine putting it?

Comment: You should do it in your button click event.  Have you given the TextBox in the InsertItemTemplate an ID?